# Edit distance in java

Tags: java, search

I have a list of names (surnames) and a simple search mechanism. I would like to have words with minor changes (typos) shown in search results.

Example search text: `braniecka`

Example result: `Branicka`, `Kraniecka`, `Braniecki`

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I'd recommend looking into an edit distance algorithm http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance

Comment: And into: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance#Java). It is a widely used algorithm.

You could also consider upgrading your solution to Lucene, especially if you are doing any production work. Lucene handles your requirement in an extremely performant way (no brute-force exhaustive search).

Comment: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance#Java

Comment: @AliBZ Updated the link with yours.

Answer (score 0):

Try using simmetrics.
Is a library for measuring string similarity and implements many algorithms.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/simmetrics/